# multiple profile type values

Tags: users

I have following requirement

I have user with multiple profile type like main profile, personal profile, and role profile

A role profile has fields like

```
role paid
role status
role start date
role subscription date
```

A single user can have multiple role profiles and above fields associated with each role profile

I heard about field collection per field which means we can have multiple values per field , But how can we have set of  multiple profile values

Example :

```
Role name : Moderator
   role paid : yes
   role status : yes 
   role start date : xxxxxx
   role subscription date : xxxxxx


Role name : testrole
   role paid : yes
   role status : no 
   role start date : xxxxxx
   role subscription date : xxxxxx
```

and continues...

Answer (score 0):

I think usage of profile2 module works only with 1 -1 relationship with user to each profile type. Node or custom entity might work better for your use case. Field collection is one way of creating such entity. This article ([Creating your own entities](http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/creating-own-entities-entity-api)) might help, if you replace task -> role_licence and task_type -> role_licence_template.